# CruiseControl.NET and TFS Labeller

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I'm facing a very simple issue but I can't find the right tool: We (in our team) currently build our Web App (.NET 3.5SP1 Based) with CC.NET, getting source code from SubVersion.

We're moving to TFS2005 (already used by other teams) but I can't find the equivalent of the SvnVersionLabeller; the specific labeller gets the latest version from the (specified) SubVersion server so I can align both Build Labels and DLLs Version.

Is there anyone already did it ? Should I do it by myself?

Am I moving in the wrong way?

We're currently using CC.NET also because we've 3 Build Servers in 3 different countries connected with slow data connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to write my own TFS Labeller for CruiseControl.NET .

Here's the url of the project on CodePlex: http://tfsrevisionlabeller.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

We customize the build number and are using the build number to set the version number of the assemblies.

Take a look at this blog post by Martin Woodward: [Aligning Build Numbers with Assembly Versions in TFS2008](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/000417.html)

I believe you can do the same with TFS 2005.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't cover my scenario.
It refers to a Build with TFS...I'm using CC.NET to build the whole set of source code.
The only information I'm looking for is the latest changeset number for a specific TFS Project...thru a "standard" CC.NET labeller so the same build number is used as label for tagging.

Answer (score 0):

I created a project for tfs labeller in [github](https://github.com/tobyqin/ccnet.tfsrevisionlabeller).

- Download the `ccnet.tfsrevisionlabeller.plugin.dll` file from Release page
- Copy it into the **CruiseControl.NET Installation folder** (e.g. `C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server`),
- Restart the CruiseControl.NET Service to use the plugin.

Finally update your project like below example.

Example:

```
 <labeller type="tfsRevisionLabeller">
    <project>$/Main/MyTestProject</project>
    <server>http://server:8080/tfs/Collection</server>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <domain>domain</domain>
    <major>1</major>
    <minor>4</minor>
 </labeller>
```